# How do you create a new column based on Max value of 1 column and Category of another?

Tags: max, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I am working with a bunch of data for my job creating status reports on the documents that we are working through that we then assign to an area. We decided to use PowerBI as an interactive way to see where everything is at.

Using Power BI Desktop I've created a new table that excludes documents that are not ready for QC but we have several different statuses. Instead of creating a new table for each status type (since some can be grouped together) I would like to create a new column that has the grouped status value's Max for each area. The higher the Status Value the further it is from being complete.

EX:

| Record: | Area: | Status Value: | Max Status Value: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 152385 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 354354 | B | 2 | 3 |
| 131322 | B | 3 | 3 |
| 132136 | A | 2 | 2 |
| 213513 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 351315 | B | 2 | 3 |

If anyone knows how to get the Max Status Value column that would greatly help. I did find another post (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/LOOKUPVALUE-return-min-max-of-values-found/td-p/657534) that was similar but I'm still new to DAX and could not figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

This post actually helped me answer the question.
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Maxifs-Power-Query/m-p/1693606

The only difference I made was getting rid of the true/false portion to receive my results. Thus my result was:

```
Max Status Value = 
VAR vMaxVal=
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Status Value] ),
        ALLEXCEPT (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Area]
        )
    )
RETURN
    vMaxVal
```